# Add an xcode project in a repository tfs

Tags: ios, xcode, git, tfs

I'm trying to connect to a repository tfs a written project with xcode 5.
I'm using git-tf and it seems that the configuration in xcode 5 is correct.
The problem that feedback occurs when authentication with the TFS repository.
In xcode 5 open preferences and go in the accounts. I enter the login information with the url and in response I Access denied credentials are incorrect.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I was encountering the same issues when trying to authenticate in Xcode 5. 
Make sure that you enabled Basic Authentication for your user profile for the TFS user account and that you selected "New Team project + GIT" instead of "New Team Project".

You can also try to clone the repository by using Terminal. Type the following command into Terminal and replace XXXXX with your values.

```
git clone https://XXXXX.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/XXXXX
```

Then provide your credentials. Terminal will now clone the repository when authentication succeeds and your credentials will be saved to your keychain. Now when you try to authenticate in Xcode it will use the saved keychain credentials and it will (probably) successfully add your TFS repository to Xcode.

I hope this will help you!

See:
http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/learn/use-git-and-xcode-with-tfs.aspx 
for more information

Comment: The cloning in terminal first method allowed Xcode to authenticate. Thanks!

Comment: How do you "enable Basic Authentication for the user" in local Team Foundation Server Express? Searching for answers to the local TFS problems is frustrating because most of the time, the result only shows Visual Studio Online version, which has different menus & options than local TFS Express.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/share-your-xcode-projects-vs

Share your Xcode projects in Visual Studio Online using a Git repository. Or, if your team project uses TFVC instead of Git, you can use the git-tf command line tool to check your files into Visual Studio Online.

Enable alternate credentials

You can’t sign in to Xcode with an account that contains an @ character, so you’ll have to enable alternate credentials.